# Reducing page height in @media

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reduce my page height in desktop @media above `768px` but it's not responding to the div selector:

```
<div class="parallax-window 
fullscreen" data- 
parallax="scroll" data- 
image- 
src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads/2019/08/d
ownload-2.png" data-ios- 
fix="true" data-over- 
scroll-fix="true" data- 
android-fix="true">
```

Tried css

```
@media (min-width: 768px){.parallax-window {height: 50%;}}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 768px){.parallax-window {height:600px;}}
```

Doesn't work [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Answer (score 2):

Change the code with that:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
section.cover.fullscreen.image-bg {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which result you expect? because if you look with inspector the div is now 600px.

Comment: I expected the height of the div to be reduced so it's not as high. As in less black space height wise. Body reduced in height, footer closer to the top because of it etc

Comment: the div 'parallax-window' with my code is 600px now, if you apply same rule try to apply same rule to: cover fullscreen image-bg and see result if is what you expect

Comment: You mean `@media screen only and (min-width: 768px){.fullscreen image-bg{height: 600px;}}`?

Comment: for that i add  `#main {
    height: 600px;
}`

Comment: is simple go to your website use inspector add the line with media query main and section.cover.fullscreen.image-bg and work, is impossible you can't do that :)

Comment: mmh, i can't help you from here... are you sure you clean cache?

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for your time